# Environment variables are not being detected by Laravel Application

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to deploy my app on google cloud but having some trouble.

In my app.yaml i have

```
    env_variables:
# change these values as appropriate:
 DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST: '***'
 DEVELOPMENT_DB_USERNAME: '***'
 DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD: '***'
 DEVELOPMENT_USER_DB_NAME: '***'
 PRODUCTION_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE: '****'
 PRODUCTION_DB_USERNAME: '***'
 PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD: '***'
 PRODUCTION_USER_DB_NAME: '***'
```

In my database.php i have this if clause:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App    Engine') !== false) {
  $user_array = array(
        'driver'        =>  'mysql',
        'unix_socket'   =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE'),
        'host'          =>  '',
        'database'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_USER_DB_NAME'),
        'username'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'      =>  getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'       =>  'utf8',
        'collation'     =>  'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'        =>  ''
    );
} else {
  $user_array = array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST'),
        'database'  => getenv('DEVELOPMENT_USER_DB_NAME'),
        'username'  => getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'  => getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    );
}
```

for some reason the environment variables are not being detected when I'm trying to run migrate on my local machine.  What would be causing this.

### Update

Here is what my terminal is showing
[click here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-T_KLYRUXbkE/U7uMz4s1ZDI/AAAAAAAAFQA/s5AF0gax3Oo/w839-h250-no/test.jpg)

Comment: Just to be clear - it's not working on your local machine or not working in production or both?

Comment: I haven't tried it on the production but it's not working on the local machine.

Comment: does the order of the app.yaml matter or can the env_variables be underneath the handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environmental variables specified in app.yaml are only used and set in the dev_appserver environment. I assume you're using standard php-cgi to run artisan, which does not understand app.yaml.